# C++ same function call with different input(arrays), How can I shrink my statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am tring to use insertion sort to sort 7 different size arrays.

In main(), I know it looks silly to repeat calling the same function, but I really can't think of a way to simplify my code.

Besides, I have utilized the switch cases to generate different size arrays. Is this a wise way to do taht?

Hope anyone can help me.

I have posted my code here.:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> n = { 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, 10000 }; //Different input size
const int N = 20000; //random scale
int n0[100], n1[500], n2[1000], n3[2000], n4[5000], n5[8000], n6[10000]; //initialize input arrays
int *myArray[] = { n0, n1, n2 };



bool isAlreadyAdded(int value, int index, int *pointer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if (*pointer == value)
            return true;
        pointer++;
    }
    return false;
}

void generator(int size){

    int input_size = n[size];
    int *p, *p2; //create a pointer point to the arrays which we want to manipulate.

    switch (input_size)
    {
    case 100:
        p = n0;
        p2 = n0;
        //cout << "p = n0 :" << *p << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;

    case 500:
        p = n1;
        p2 = n1;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;
    case 1000:
        p = n2;
        p2 = n2;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;
    case 2000:
        p = n3;
        p2 = n3;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;
    case 5000:
        p = n4;
        p2 = n4;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;
    case 8000:
        p = n5;
        p2 = n5;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;
    case 10000:
        p = n6;
        p2 = n6;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Invalid input_size" << endl;
    } //end swith cases.
}

void insertion_sort(int arr[], int length){
    int j, temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && arr[j] < arr[j - 1]){
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

void writeToFile(int array[], string fileName, int length)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        myfile << array[i] << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}



int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); ++i){
        generator(i); // Parameter is the input size
    }


    insertion_sort(n0, sizeof(n0) / sizeof(n0[0]));
    insertion_sort(n1, sizeof(n1) / sizeof(n1[0]));
    insertion_sort(n2, sizeof(n2) / sizeof(n2[0]));
    insertion_sort(n3, sizeof(n3) / sizeof(n3[0]));
    insertion_sort(n4, sizeof(n4) / sizeof(n4[0]));
    insertion_sort(n5, sizeof(n5) / sizeof(n5[0]));
    insertion_sort(n6, sizeof(n6) / sizeof(n6[0]));

    //writeToFile(n0, "n0", sizeof(n0) / sizeof(n0[0]));


    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the only part of the switch that's different between cases is which array you set `p` and `p2` to point to. Can't you move the rest out of the switch?

Comment: Yes, you can abstract out all of the stuff in each `case` from the `switch` to a function. Pass in to the function the size of the array and a pointer to the array and then sort it. Call this function for each array.

Comment: Just use a vector instead of arrays, and use `resize` to make it the number of elements you want when you're ready to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are cases for compiler macros. You really don't want to end up having to update code in 100023965-zigtillion kind of places :-)

U can define a macro somewhat like this at the top of your file:

```
#define MYCODE(PARAM) p = PARAM; \
p2 = PARAM; \
for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) { \
  int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1. \
  while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) \
    tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); \
  *p = tmp; \
  //cout << *p << endl; \
  p++; 
}
```

Once you have done this, you can edit your generator function:

```
void generator(int size){
  int input_size = n[size];
  int *p, *p2; //create a pointer point to the arrays which we want to manipulate.

  switch (input_size) {
    case 100:
      MYCODE(n0);
      break;
    case 500:
      MYCODE(n1);
      break;
    // similiar for 1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, ...
  }
}
```

Big big advantage, when you later find out that its not while(x != 0) but while(x > 0) or something like that.. Comes in handy. When macros are not enough (e.g. typing becomes an issue), you can move on with C++ Templates that can handle different type code generation on the fly during compilation. Very usefull stuff for big, grown codebases.

Comment: Thank you! I have abstract out all code from each case to a macro. It looks much better.

Comment: [So, what's wrong with using macros?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro)

Comment: Macro is a terrible idea. If you can do it using macro, in 95% of cases you can as well write a template method, which will do the same and make code ten times more readable.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

Add an index:

```
#include <map>
....

vector<int> n = { 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, 10000 }; //Different input size
const int N = 20000; //random scale
int n0[100], n1[500], n2[1000], n3[2000], n4[5000], n5[8000], n6[10000]; //initialize input arrays
int *myArray[] = { n0, n1, n2 };

// index by size
map<int,int*> index= { {100,n0}, {500,n1}, {1000,n2}, {2000,n3}, {5000,n4}, {8000,n5}, {10000,n6} }; //Different input size
```

Abstract the code:

```
void all_the_things_I_did_in_the_case(int *nx,int size) {
    int input_size = n[size];
    int *p, *p2; //create a pointer point to the arrays which we want to manipulate.
    p = nx;
    p2 = nx;

        //cout << "p = n0 :" << *p << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
        {
            int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
            while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
                tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
            *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
            //cout << *p << endl;
            p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
        }
}
```

and replace the ugly generator

```
void generator(int size){
    map<int,int*>::iterator it=index.find(size);
    if(it!=index.end()) {
       all_the_things_I_did_in_the_case(it->second,size);
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid input_size" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a macro (it just generates a larger program for no good reason)... as  user2357112 suggested in a comment:

```
switch (input_size)
{
  case 100: p = n0; p2 = n0; break;
  case 500: p = n1; p2 = n1; break;
  case 1000: p = n2; p2 = n2; break;
  etc.
}
```

...**then** code your loop...

```
//cout << "p = n0 :" << *p << endl;
for (int x = 0; x != input_size; ++x) //for loop to generate "input_size" number of elements.
{
    int tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Shift right by 1.
    while (x != 0 && isAlreadyAdded(tmp, x, p2)) //Check if the generated element is already existed.
        tmp = 1 + (rand() % N); //Regenerate the element.
    *p = tmp; // let the pointer get the value of this tmp.
    //cout << *p << endl;
    p++; //Increment the pointer to pointer to next element of the array.
}
break;
```

(making community wiki as not my idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your generator as generic as `insertion_sort`

```
void generator(int *a, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        do {
            a[i]= 1 + (rand() % N);
        } while (std::find(a, a + i, a[i]) != a + i);
    }
}
```

To auto compute the size, you may also use:

```
template <std::size_t SIZE> void generator(int (&a)[SIZE]) { generator(a, size); }
```

and in your main use:

```
generator(n0);
generator(n1);
generator(n2);
generator(n3);
generator(n4);
generator(n5);
generator(n6);
```